# EF 4.1 in VS 2010 not showing enum option

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, enums, entity-framework-4.1

**The Problem**

- I made a DB model using EF 4 in VS 2010.
- I wanted an enum, realised 4.1 had this, so downloaded and installed
  4.1 update 1 from MS. (from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825)
- Re-opened my project, right clicked an Int32 field, there is no
  "convert to enum" option like examples on blogs about EF 4.1. (like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-enums-june-ctp.aspx)
- Looked at many websites as to cause, found nothing.
- Created a brand new test project, created entity diagram model-first,
  tried again, still no option.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: **I wanted an enum, realised 4.1** where did you see such a thing, 4.1 does not support enums

Comment: Well, as Far as I know, ToEnum method must be your implementation using static Enum class.

Comment: I'm also not seeing the option in EF4.3. When is this actually going to be added? It really annoys me when they show these great new features in demos, but then take months to actually release them.

Comment: This is scheduled for release in EF5.0. I believe the delay is that it requires some features from .NET 5.0 / C# 5.0, so they are all being released at the same time.

Comment: @BradR is there any news on when C#5 will be released?

Comment: @Johann de Swardt - it's good timing actually, they just released the beta, which requires .NET 4.5. [Detail here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The June CTP is not Entity Framework 4.1, it is the preview of the next version. Enums are not in EF 4.1, they were a planned feature but they removed it when 4.1 was released.

You will need to download the June CTP, you can download it here but you do so at your own risk as this is pre-release software and not designed for use in a production environment:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26660

Comment: Ahh ok. Sorry must of made a mental jump there somewhere.